# Destination Host unreachable does not result in an errorlevel 1

Tags: batch-file, ping, errorlevel

So at work we have some Computers that we have to load softwares onto and usually when I connect my laptop to the computer by an ethernet cable i have to set my IPv4 adress to `10.10.1.99` because the computer usually has `10.10.1.101` as IP adress then I load the software onto that computer.
Now sometimes the computer has a wrong IP preset for example `10.41.246.70` or `10.42.246.71`.

Since we dont have an easy and fast way to check for what ip the computer has i have written a little scrip that changes the IPv4 of my laptop to the most common IP's the Computers usually have and let it ping those IP's:
The code looks like this and it goes through around 8 IP's that it checks:

```
cls
echo Searching.
netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet" static 10.10.1.99 255.255.255.0 >nul: 2>nul:
ping -w 4 -n 3 10.10.1.101
if !errorlevel!==0 (
    set activeip=10.10.1.101
    goto :ipfound
)
```

Now this code usually works just fine, in 99% of the cases its one of the 8 IP's that we know.
The problem is that sometimes instead of "Request timed out" I get "Destination Host unreachable" which for some reason seems to not be an error and when I do get Destination Host unreachable the script thinks it has found the right IP.
Now is there a way to go around this for example by adding some kind of:

```
if output == Destination Host Unreachable (goto next IP)
```

or is there a way to tell the script that destination host unreachable is also an error.

Thanks to everyone who can help in any way.

Comment: Could you please format your code as a proper code block? It's hard to read like that.

Comment: Are you even sure that `ping` should modify `errorlevel`? UNIX `ping` has a return value which is 0 in case of success, and 1 in case of failure. Can you catch `ping`'s return value instead of the `errorlevel`?

Comment: @Dominique yes, it will set errorlevel, problem is that `destination host unreachable` is still a reply and is not set to `errorlevel` `1` I cannot recall what it sets, but think it was minus figure.. Ping only changes `0` and `1` between `ping request could not find host` `(1)`, `request timed out` `(1)` and `reply from` `(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Reply from xx.xx.xx.xx: Destination Host Unreachable` is technically still a reply.. `:)`

You can use `findstr` to manipulate your `errorlevel`

```
ping -w 4 -n 3 10.10.1.101 | findstr /i "TTL"
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" echo Success
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" echo Failed
```

Keep in mind that the `errorlevel` here is set based on the result of `findstr` (whether your `findstr` string matched what you asked it to find).

To demonstrate, this will return `errorlevel` of `0` because the search string was met:

```
ping -w 4 -n 3 10.10.1.101 | findstr /i "Destination Host Unreachable"
echo %errorlevel%
```

So finally, to ammend your script to always check for actual `reply from` and not `destination host unreachable`, and move to the next IP until we find the active IP, simply do:

```
set "ips=10.10.1.101 10.10.1.102 10.10.1.103 10.10.1.104"
for %%i in (%ips%) do ( 
    ping -w 4 -n 3 %%i | findstr /i "TTL"

    if "!errorlevel!"=="0" (
        set "activeip=%%i"
        goto :ipfound
  )
)
```

You have to just change the list of IP's you want where I `set` my IP's.

Also, I am assuming that you have `EnableDelayedExpansion` set somewhere already, seeing that you are using it.

Comment: Omg thanks a thousand times! thats exactly what i searched for. thanks for the extremely quick and detailed answer I'll try it later when I have some time but i'm sure it will work perfectly :D

Comment: @Kyotai No problem at all, just let me know if you have any issues.